# Интерфейс IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net

Появились некоторые вопросы касательно реализацию IDisposable по шаблону, который предлагает Микрософт, где еще задействован финализатор.

Там пишется, что если программист забыл позаботится о ручном вызове Dispose, то нужно реализовать финализатор.

Почему в финализатор вызывает метод Dispose со значением false, что приводит к освобождению только неуправляемых ресурсов?

Если верить статьям, то сборщик мусора видит, что у объекта есть финализатор и помещает его в отдельную очередь => как я понимаю, объект считается удаленным после финализации.

Или я что-то упускаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сборщик мусора в .NET вполне хорошо справляется с удалением управляемых ресурсов. Однако же о неуправляемых ресурсах он мало что знает. Так вот если вызывается финализатор, то можно считать, что до управляемых ресурсов у сборщика мусора руки уже дошли (точнее, вот-вот дойдут), а вот об освобождении неуправляемых нужно позаботиться самому программисту. Поэтому в таком случае вызывается `Dispose(false)`.

Comment: Плюс ссылки на управляемые "ресурсы" в финализаторе могут быть недействительны, и пользоваться ими нельзя.